# I'm developing an Angular WebApp but I cant seem to get *ngFor to work

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I've honestly tried everything I've seen, importing in only and both the app-routing.module and the app.module, adding CommonModule as well as well as ng build and reserve. Someone please save me from myself, I've been on this for 2 hours now and it's the last piece of my WebApp, thanks in advance.

app-routing.module

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DisplayViewComponent } from './pages/display-view/display-view.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo:'RunninghillWordApp', pathMatch: "full"},
  {path: 'RunninghillWordApp', component: DisplayViewComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes),CommonModule],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DisplayViewComponent } from './pages/display-view/display-view.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, DisplayViewComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
```

*edit
added my html just incase the error is there

```
        <div class="history-display-container">
            <!-- Display previous sentences -->
            <a class="history-item" *ngFor="let item of history">
                <p>{{item.text}}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
```

**edit
adding my component in case error lies there

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SentenceService } from '../../services/sentence.service';
import { WordService } from '../../services/word.service';
import { Sentence } from '../../models/sentence.model';
import { Word } from '../../models/word.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-display-view',
  templateUrl: './display-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display-view.component.scss']
})
export class DisplayViewComponent implements OnInit {

  history: Sentence[];
  words: Word[];

  constructor(private sentenceService: SentenceService, private wordService: WordService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        console.log(params);
  }
)

//populate sentences and words arrays
this.sentenceService.getSentences().subscribe((sentences: Sentence[]) =>{
  console.log(sentences);
  this.history = sentences;
});
}
```

The error I get is

```
Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.
```

**edit
After restarting my browser and VSCode, the errror is now :

```
NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

Comment: You don't have your html code on here, but looks like you have `ngForOf` instead of `ngFor` in there based on the error message.

Comment: Also in your routes, you probably want your first route to match any route that's not there by having the `*`. `{path: '*', redirectTo:'RunninghillWordApp', pathMatch: "full"},`. You would also need to move it to the bottom so if there is another path above that it goes there instead of getting redirected because it will match with `*` first.

Comment: @JacobP just added my html just too, will add the suggested edits to my routes

Comment: We need to see your component code as well. And we'll need to know what your data for `history` looks like. There's nothing wrong with your HTML code, so the problem must be elsewhere - perhaps on the component, so please post that.

Comment: According to this: https://www.freakyjolly.com/resolved-cant-bind-to-ngforof-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-div/#.XyypCq-SmUk it's usually an import issue, but your imports look fine. I would also try running `npm install` again and stopping the app and restarting it.

Comment: you have defined history in your code. you need history to be an array.

Comment: @Rick, it doesn't necessarily have to be an `array`, it just has to be `iterable`.

Comment: @Jacob that was actually one of the articles i came across and made me clean up my imports, rerunning npm install seems to have no effect either

Comment: @Rick and Muirik history is an iterable array of type Sentence, the log shows it has data and is working

Comment: Maybe the problem is just the initialization. `history: Sentence[] = [];  words: Word[] = [];`

Comment: @JacobP I just tried that, but that got me trying to see what's in history, and it's empty for some reason

Comment: i suggest to remove node_modules, package-lock.json and run npm install again, you are actually doing right. if it's a problem with history object, you should see another error

Comment: console log history. it's probably not populated

Comment: @Rick it is, with this: {sentences: Array(7)}
sentences: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object

Comment: @Rick but i cant seem to iterate through it, it's as if it's not an array

Comment: @ThusoluminatiAl-ZawahiriKhar You are receiving an object with a property `sentences`of type `array` you need to receive that object as `any` and set the local property: `this.history = [...obj.sentences];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, your are receiving an object `{ sentences: [...] }` from your service, not an array. You will need to change the function receiving the result and then set the local `history` property.

```
//populate sentences and words arrays
this.sentenceService.getSentences().subscribe((result: any) =>{
  this.history = [...result.sentences];
});
```

Comment: a hero among men, truly

Comment: this is going to cause your entire result to be an array of 1 element. it will make your ngFor loop work, but may not be the solution you are looking for. you may want to try *ngFor="let item of history.sentences", instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 <div class="history-display-container" *ngFor="let item of history">
    <a class="history-item">{{item.text}}</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Just did, no difference

Answer (score 0):

it looks like sentences is an array but history is an object. try this:

```
*ngFor="let item of history.sentences"
```